# MUI v5 Date Pickers: Is there a way to remove the SwitchViewButton?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

Is there any way to remove the SwitchViewButton (the one that displays the month and year) from the calendar picker or replace it with my own component?

Their API provides the following prop to modify them in the StaticDatePicker:
`components = { LeftArrowButton?: elementType, LeftArrowIcon?: elementType, OpenPickerIcon?: elementType, RightArrowButton?: elementType, RightArrowIcon?: elementType, SwitchViewButton?: elementType, SwitchViewIcon?: elementType }`

But when I try sending 'null' to any of them, it completely ignores them and renders the same thing.

[Date Picker view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OdZ6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `null` to them, I was able to get them to not display by passing an `sx` value to each one's props.

So instead of:

```js
<DatePicker
     components={{SwitchViewButton: null}}
/>
```

You can do:

```js
<DatePicker
     componentProps={{
          switchViewButton: { sx: { display: 'none' } }
     }}
/>
```

It's not perfect, but it gets the job done, at least in my limited experience. I think this is because when you pass `null` to the `component` prop, it just uses the default.

**Note**: The `components` prop uses Pascal case (ActionBar), while `componentsProps` uses camel case (actionBar) per the [documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-components/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<DatePicker disableOpenPicker />
```

Add this attribute to your `DatePicker` component and just control the opening with `open={}`.